# Kaggleのチームのついて

Tags: kaggle

今、自分は機械学習について勉強しています。そこでKaggleに取り組んでいます。しかしタイタニック号の生死の予測が終わって、チームを組んで色々なことを学びたいと思いました。しかし、チームを募集してもなかなか集まりません。自分はTwitterで募集をかけました。どこで募集すればチームは見つかりますか？

Comment: 技術的な問題(エラー等)を解決するための質問をすべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: @sugiyamath さん、このような場合、[通報機能](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)や（sugiyamath さんはまだギリギリご利用いただけませんが）[クローズ投票機能](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)が用意されております。ご参考までに :)

Comment: @Rikubon さん、スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　せっかくご質問いただいたところ申し訳ないのですが、今回のご質問はプログラミングそのものとはやや離れた内容であるため、スタック・オーバーフローの[質問できる範囲](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)から外れているかもしれません。おそらく現在ついているマイナス表は、質問の仕方が悪いという評価ではなく内容がミスマッチだという評価と思われます。ご承知おきくださいませ。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaggle内のディスカッションでチームを探す人がいます。
https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/32696

基本的に[インド人とアメリカ人が大半を占める](https://www.kaggleusercontent.com/kf/7443367/eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..pnrU-j3V2Yi9tZrFvHBc_g.3O7MqFf_7F3tgfa9O-IUv9LBYEAKG9J7gXSFtG6MrlTXeeLEQdQvL8YUHAFp-Jcdue3MPPNOa8CFKtXSgmdS3TUUB09-cxG0L3CENUcDSg6kt8by9zoGdBjNfKBDtHpU1eEeFHZbUTsSFfd0cuxJfUUQ4ChXuI50_iQ54BcXxyIVnPZe5kWewsl-EKCGsrwD.m3JbDOeL8_iM_kYHz6NVmw/__results__.html#In-which-country-do-you-currently-reside?)ので、英語でチームを探すほうが見つかりやすいでしょう。

ただし、チームを組むことは必須要件ではありません。1人でコツコツとコンペに参加する人も多くいます。一人だからといって、学べないわけではありません。

学ぶことが目的であれば、Kaggle以外にも方法はあります。

- 書籍を読む。
- githubでコードを読む。
- arXivで論文を読む。
- 共有タスクと公開データセットで学ぶ。

Kaggle内で学びたい場合は、コンペだけではなく、ディスカッションやカーネルをみて学ぶ方法があります。

Comment: 技術的な質問ではありませんでしたが、わざわざ返信いただきありがとうございました！参考にさせていただきます！